# Growth accounting: technological progress grows at near zero rate

Tags: macroeconomics, economic-growth, solow

In a growth accounting exercise I backed out the time path of technical progress augmenting a factor. Annual growth rate of this factor saving innovation is very close to zero in the last few years. So, its contribution to growth per head diminished. Can we also say, in these later years the augmentation was more like neutral than factor specific?